Running `collecstatic` returns [Errno 13] Permission denied in docker compose
I run my django app in Docker. I recently tried running collecstatic and instead was given this error code:
>docker-compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
...

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/static/admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.bbfb788a849e.svg.gz'

I added a USER at the end of my Dockerfile so that the USER isn't root which I know is a security vulnerability. Here is my Dockerfile:
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV COLUMNS 80

#install Debian and other dependencies that are required to run python apps(eg. git, python-magic).
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --force-yes python3-pip ffmpeg git libmagic-dev libpq-dev gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set working directory for Docker image
WORKDIR /code/

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .

# Create a custom non-root user
RUN useradd -m example-user

# Grant necessary permissions to write directories and to user 'example-user'
RUN mkdir -p /code/media /code/static && \
    chown -R example-user:example-user

 1. List item

 /code/media /code/static

# Change permissions of /code directory
RUN chmod -R 755 /code

# Switch to the non-root user. All this avoids running Celery with root/superuser priviledges which is a security risk
USER example-user

And my docker-compose-yml file:
#version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    #command: python /code/manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000
    command: gunicorn mysite.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - celery
    environment:
      -  "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=scret_key"
      -  "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS=0" 
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False" # new
      -  "ACCESS_KEY_ID=scret_id"
      -  "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=scret_key"
      -  "STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=bucket"
      -  "S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN=domain"
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
      
    user: example-user
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
  redis:
    image: redis:6
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A mysite worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    environment:
      -  "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=scret_key"
      -  "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS=0" 
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False" # new
      -  "ACCESS_KEY_ID=scret_id"
      -  "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=scret_key"
      -  "STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=name"
      -  "S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN=domain"
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0

    user: example-user
volumes:
  postgres_data:

I also added chmod -R 755 /code/media /code/static however it still did not work and the results are the same. When I run  docker-compose exec web ls -l /code/static the results indicate that all files/folders are being run as root execpt staticfiles.json:
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 1 root      root       4096 Apr  5 05:42 admin
drwxrwxrwx 1 root      root       4096 Sep 21 22:36 css
drwxrwxrwx 1 root      root       4096 Sep 21 22:36 human
drwxrwxrwx 1 root      root       4096 Sep 18 18:42 img
-rw-r--r-- 1 user-mani user-mani 13091 Sep 21 22:36 staticfiles.json
drwxrwxrwx 1 root      root       4096 Sep 21 22:36 transcribe


I'd RUN ./manage.py collectstatic in your Dockerfile (as root), like in this answer.

@DavidMaze If following this solution wouldn't that mean I have to rebuild every time I want to run collectstatic?

...yes?  But you need to rebuild every time you change your code anyways, and ./manage.py collectstatic is a build step itself.  If you don't want an isolated immutable image, a non-Docker Python virtual environment might be a better setup.

@DavidMaze Thanks. The comment you linked returned error environs.EnvError: Environment variable "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY" not set and failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput" did not complete successfully. However after removing the line, running docker-compose down and instead manually entering >docker-compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear it worked. However now when I run docker-compose exec web ls -l... it shows example-user instead of root. The only change I made was to comment RUN ...  collectstatic --noinput

@DavidMaze And of course now running docker-compose exec web ... collecstatic there is no problem at all. No other change to the dockerfile. I'm very new to this and not sure why so thanks for your help.

@DavidMaze I added a comment in case you are interested.

@DavidMaze
# Set working directory for Docker image
WORKDIR /code/

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .

#collect static files
#RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Create non-root user
RUN useradd -m example-user

# Grant necessary permissions to write directories and to user 'user-mani'
RUN mkdir -p /code/media /code/static && \
    chown -R  example-user: example-user /code/media /code/static

# Switch to the non-root user.
USER  example-user

There are the only changes made
